# Clojure ^shared in namespace

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am following the [pedestal tutorial](https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial), and I noticed the `^shared` annotation in the code, like below :

```
(ns ^:shared tutorial-client.behavior
    (:require [clojure.string :as string]
              [io.pedestal.app.messages :as msg]))
```

What is it useful for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ^shared annotation is for indicating to the ClojureScript compiler to compile this .clj file, where it would normally ignore it. This lets you write shared code that can be run on the client and server (as long as it doesn't use platform specific code). This was before cljx and cljc files and AFAIK is specific to the Pedestal build process, not part of vanilla ClojureScript.

The supported way to write platform specific code is using Reader Conditionals, new in Clojure 1.7.

As a side note, Pedestal App is effectively deprecated, Pedestal Server is still maintained.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that code should be compiled both as clojure, for use server-side, and as clojurescript, for use in the browser.

From the [pedestal wiki](https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial/wiki/Testing#sharing-code):

> When compilation occurs, any Clojure namespaces marked :shared will
>   also be compiled to ClojureScript.
>
> ```
> (ns ^:shared tutorial-client.behavior
>     (:require [clojure.string :as string]
>               [io.pedestal.app.messages :as msg]))
> ```
>
> For now, these files must contain the common subset of Clojure and
>   ClojureScript. A new feature of Clojure 1.6, feature expressions, will
>   allow us to break free from this restriction.